# Spark environment variables scope and reading with log4j2

Tags: apache-spark, environment-variables, log4j2

I am working on a Spark application running in cluster mode in YARN with log4j2. I am providing a log4j2.xml file which is being picked up for logging. I am facing problem with fetching environmental variables in logging. I want to fetch app-name, app-id, application-attempt, container-name and logging-level. I may direct this log with syslog appender to a centralised log server. I am using these environment variables as a prefix to log statements. I am able to fetch app-name, app-id, application-attempt but I couldn't find any environmental variables for container-name and logging-level.And also I am not able to fetch any environmental variables in executors. It looks like those variables scope is limited to driver only. How can I get environment variables for container-name and logging-level at run time and how to get these environment variables in executors?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration status = "INFO">
        <Appenders>
            <Console name ="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
               <PatternLayout pattern = "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${sys:spark.yarn.app.id}:${sys:spark.app.name}:${sys:spark.yarn.app.attemptId}[%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
    <Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref = "Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `${env:key}` lookup instead of the `${sys:key}` lookup. The former is for OS level environment variables, the latter is for Java system properties.

See also https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html